# How to remove a Alphabetical char between two numbers in a cell in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

[image]

Goal: I have a column called Resolution. What you can see in the picture. Let's say the first cell 1600 x 900 I need to get rid of the x in order to have an integer value. So the results should be 1600 900. How can I do that?

I have tried to search online I could not find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Best_Resolution'] = df['Best_Resolution'].str.replace('x', ' ')
```

Or if you want the value as integer:

```
df['Best_Resolution'] = (
    df['Best_Resolution'].str.replace('x', '')
    .astype(int)
)
```

It might fail if there are values that cannot be converted to integer.